# URL Image issue iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 2 main small image buttons say **aBtn** & **bBtn**. When i click **aBtn / bBtn** i Generate 6 image url as default checking the condition that the **images are not nil**. In the 6 images if some images are empty then i avoid that empty image alone & set the frame accordingly. When i click from **aBtn to bBtn**, i have the time delay. It is due to checking the 6  url images generate without nil/empty image each time & by setting the frame position accordingly.

This is the code i used to display the images & check the condition from the 6 url images data is not nil if something say 3rd url image is nil it will be avoided. How to overcome the delay to display the images?

```
    NSMutableString *strUrl;
    int i;
    int j=7;
    int k=0;
    xorigin=350;
    int cou=1;

    for( i=1;i<j;i++){

        strUrl=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc]init];


        [strUrl appendFormat:@"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/images2.solestruck.com/%@%@%@%@%@%@%@)-01060%d.jpg",
         [[[[shoeDetailDict objectForKey:@"vendorName"] lowercaseString] lowercaseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"],@"-shoes/",[[shoeDetailDict objectForKey:@"vendorName"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"],@"-shoes-",[[shoeDetailDict objectForKey:@"productName"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"],@"-(",[[prdcolorimgArray objectAtIndex:tagedColor] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"],i];

        NSURL *imageUrl=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strUrl];

        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        NSLog(@"imageurl colors : %@",strUrl);

        if(i==4){

            imageView.frame =CGRectMake(25, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width*80)/100,(self.view.frame.size.height*40)/100);
            [imageView setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
        }

        else{

            if(data != nil ){
                cou++;
                imageView.frame =CGRectMake(xorigin, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width*80)/100,(self.view.frame.size.height*40)/100);
                [imageView setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
                xorigin=xorigin+320;

            }
        }
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [productScroll addSubview:imageView];
        productScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width)*cou, (self.view.frame.size.height*40)/100);
        productScroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);

        k++;
    }
```

Comment: Well I guess the delay is the time it takes to download the images from the website?

Comment: try using NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:

Comment: No the delay is due to check the images if the data is not nil @ trojanfoe

Comment: @Saha_pre, where does `setImageWithURL:` come from?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I use **SDWebImage** UIImageView+WebCache.h (setImageWithURL:) to display the images alone.

Comment: this doesnt make much sense: `setImageWithURL:` will download the image that you just downloaded as NSDate

Comment: How do you know **where** the delay is?

Comment: i get a delay when i check url with if(data != nil ) this .

Comment: But **HOW** do you know that — it is impossible that that line causes trouble.

Comment: The delay is bcoz of the NSData i have used to find the nil images. Is there anyother way to check the url async ??

Comment: Just download all images like I mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502252/462556 and check what URL was invalid

Comment: Hi @Yanny, where can i check the error image when am using dispatch_async ? sry that i don hav any idea abt dispatch_async. can u pls tell me or give any example link?

Comment: @Saha_pre, just load NSData like you do now. Than check whether data is present and user [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:]

Comment: @Yanny Hey thx :), It worked with the one u have posted as answer.

Comment: @Yanny, I used **dispatch_async** to make the url image display fast and i overcame the delay but as i am using NSData *data, still i cannot overcome the delay completely. any solution for that?

Comment: @Preethi dispatch_async - mean that this code will be done without stopping current thread. dispatch_get_main_queue() mean that this code will be done on main thread, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0) mean that this code will be done in background thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` that load information synchronously.

Try to load all images first and than put them on the scroll view.

Try to use this code:

```
- (void) prepareImages {
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        NSMutableArray * imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        // Load all images here
        [self imagesLoaded:imagesArray]
    });
}
- (void) imagesLoaded:(NSArray*) images {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Display images here
    });
}
```